Log all incoming requests and response details in a table
How to log incoming request details and corresponding response in table in cloud gateway.
String logId = service.logRequest(name.toString(),request.getURI().getRawPath(), String.valueOf(request.getMethod()),remoteAddr,"",new Date());

Able to fetch the request details
Storing the details in table. But issues comes when response details have to be stored in corresponding request row.
Previously in ZUUL used to store the LogId like below.
Request
RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
ctx.put("REQ-LOG-ID",LogId); 

Response
String requestLogId = (String) ctx.get("REQ-LOG-ID");
//store the response details to corresponding Id

Whats the replacement in Cloud gateway? We're using Spring-Boot 3.2.0.
